# Django HttpResponseRedirect with reverse is not working

Tags: django

In the form, everything is working, the less HttpResponseRedirect
I'm trying to redirect the contents of the form to the `rateio.html`. However, this showing the error:

`NoReverseMatch at /proposal/
Reverse for 'rateio/' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'table': .......`

What I am finding strange is that I'm pointing to the `rateio` with `reverse('rateio/', ...` only that Django is looking for `/proposal/`

Someone could tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you for attention.

**views.py**

```
def proposal(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Proposal(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        validate, content = table_split(request.POST)
        if validate==True:
            table, priority, total_sum  = valido(content)
            json_priority = simplejson.dumps(priority)
            json_total_sum = simplejson.dumps(total_sum)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('rateio/', kwargs={'table':table, 'priority' : json_priority, 'total_sum' : json_total_sum}))
        if validate==False:
            return render_to_response('proposal.html', {'form' : form, 'not_validate' : 'Incorrectly filled in proposal fill again'}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return render_to_response('proposal.html', {'form' : form, 'not_validate' : 'Incorrectly filled in proposal fill again'}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
else:
    form = Proposal()
    return render_to_response('proposal.html', {'form' : form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

def rateio(request,data):
    return render_to_response('rateio.html', {'table':data[table], 'priority' : data[priority], 'total_sum' : data[total_sum]}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^rateio/$', 'mge.core.views.rateio'),
url(r'^proposal/$', 'mge.core.views.proposal'),
```

**proposal.html**

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    .....
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two errors.

Firstly, the first parameter to `reverse` is the view name, not the URL. So it should be 'mge.core.views.rateio' as in urls.py. Or even better, give the pattern an explicit name - `name="ratio"` and use that.

Secondly, you have three kwargs you're trying to pass, but the ratio URL does not accept any parameters. What are you hoping to do with those values? Two of them are JSON docs, you wouldn't want to pass those in the URL.

Comment: if i use `return render_to_response ('rateio.html', {'table': table, 'priority': json_priority, 'total_sum': json_total_sum}, context_instance = RequestContext (request))` works perfectly. The problem is that with a refresh of the data page of the form is sent back. With the reverse I plan to eliminate sending back data of the form.

Comment: Fine, but you actually need a URL and a view that accept those parameters.

Comment: Could provide an example of a URL that accepts several parameter?

Comment: You can find that in the tutorial. I still don't understand why you're converting to JSON though.

Comment: because of rateio.html. This page has: `<script>function Tabela($scope) {
      $scope.description = {{ priority|safe }};
   ....
</script>` and `{% block corpo %}

<table>
{% for i in table %}
 <tr>
  {% for s in i %}
         <td>{{ s }}</td>
       {% endfor %}  
     </tr> 
 {% endfor %}
</table>

{{ json_total_sum|safe }}
{% endblock %}`

Comment: But that's the job of the rateio view to send those parameters to the template. It doesn't need to accept them in JSON in the first place.